# Task Parallelism - Task OnCompleted trigger on after all ContinueWith

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I am facing a problem on processing the task.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(new Action)

I have a main task with multiple ContinueWith, but when i return the main task and add a delegate on the OnCompleted, it is triggered after the main task is processed and not after all the ContinueWith

My question is, is there a way to know when all the continue with is finished?

Here is my current code.

```
runningTask.Start();
    runningTask.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() =>
        {
             KeyValuePair<int, Func<bool>> validator = validationList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == runningTask.Id);
             bool shouldContinue = validator.Value();
             if (shouldContinue)
             {
                  validationList.Remove(validator.Key);
                  PerformExecutionByQueue();
             }
         });
```

runningTask is created like this

```
Task runningTask = new Task(delegate method);
Task secondTask = runningTask.ContinueWith(delegate method);
```

and so on. . .

Comment: Please tag this with the language you're using.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to execute something when a task finishes, just use ContinueWith on the _proper_ task. TaskAwaiter is primarily used by the compiler and I wouldn't be surprised if OnComplete fires always when a specific task finishes executing, not when the tasks's state changes (eg to RanToCompletion, Cancelled or Faulted).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i've also tried running it on continuewith with creationoption of rantocompletion but it also triggers after the mainTask

Comment: After which task? If you want it to run after `secondTask`, you should  call `secondTask.ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the results of all of the calls to `ContinueWith` in a collection of some sort, and then use `Task.WhenAll` to execute some code when they have all finished.

Comment: changed the answer to this, much more logical and fixes the actual problem without any additional field

Answer (score 1):

When you call `ContinueWith`, try passing in `TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent`.  That will tell the task to treat the continuation as part of the parent task, and to not complete the parent task until the continuation has also completed.  This assumes, of course, the parent task has not *already* completed; if it has, the continuation will be executed inline when you call `ContinueWith()`.

Answer (score 1):

`ContinueWith` creates a `secondTask` that will run only after `runningTask` is finished. `secondTask` does not prevent `runningTask` from finishing, so the `OnCompleted` event will fire immediatelly after `runningTask` finishes.

If you want to prevent `runningTask` from finishing while `secondTask` still runs, use [TaskContinuationOptions.AttachToParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in ContinueWith, eg:

```
Task secondTask = runningTask.ContinueWith(delegate method,
                     TaskContinuationOptions.AttachToParent);
```

`AttachToParent` prevents its parent task from finishing until all child tasks have finished. An added bonus is that attached tasks will appear as child tasks under their parent in Visual Studio's Task View

Comment: I've tried this one but it still triggers after the runningTask.

Comment: Are you starting `runningTask` before calling `ContinueWith()`?  If so, the task may complete before the continuation is registered, in which case your awaiter callback may be invoked before `secondTask` completes.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by just adding an event on the class level and calling it on the last continue with.