# Reporting Progress from Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task

Is there a way to know the status of individual Task while using the WhenAll() or WaitAll() methods of Task.
When I use await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()) for every task that completes I would like to know that the task has completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task Parallelism - Task OnCompleted trigger on after all ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856348/task-parallelism-task-oncompleted-trigger-on-after-all-continuewith)

Comment: @BugFinder it's not exactly I am looking, I want to run all the Task asynchronously and wait for all of them to complete but at the same time, I also want to get notified for every single task that is completed.

Comment: if you launch each task with a continue with you get notified on completion

Comment: if I use continue with it will wait till the first task is completed and then it will start the second task I don't want that behavior.

Comment: read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43929319/using-continuewith-with-multiple-tasks it has suggestions on how to do what you want cleaner.. continuewith can work its just messier

Comment: There are _lots_ of ways to monitor progress of your task status, depending on exactly what you want to do. Idiomatic progress reporting, e.g. via `IProgress<T>`, will give you continuous updating (assuming your tasks are modified to support that). But, based on the tiny bit of information you've shared in your question, it sounds like all you really want to do is call `Task.WhenAny()` instead of `WhenAll()`, so that as each task completes, the wait will complete and let you know which tasks completed. You can put that in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

To report progress from an `async` or concurrent process use the `IProgress<T>` abstraction. Using the `Progress<T>` implmentation you can easily capture the current context and run your progress update / completion expression on the ui context while doing your work in the background:

```
public class WorkItem {
    public async Task DoWork(IProgress<bool> completionNotification) {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        //Work Done
        completionNotification.Report(true);
    }

    //Get, Set, Fire Property change etc
    public bool Completed {
        get; set;
    }
}

public class ViewModel {
    public async void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var workitemTasks = WorkItems.Select(workItem =>
            workItem.DoWork(new Progress<bool>(done => workItem.Completed = done)))
            .ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(workitemTasks);
    }

    //Get, Set, Fire Property change etc
    public IEnumerable<WorkItem> WorkItems {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

**[More Info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)**

**[Reporting Progress From Async Tasks @StephenCleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)**

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a much nicer way to do this, but here is a raw class which takes an array of unstarted tasks and fires an event each time some of the tasks completes execution:

```
public class TaskBatchRunner
{
    private Task[] _tasks;

    public event EventHandler<Task> TaskCompleted;

    public TaskBatchRunner(Task[] tasks)
    {
        _tasks = tasks.Select(t =>
            new Task(() =>
            {
                t.ContinueWith(OnTaskCompleted);
                t.Start();
            })).ToArray();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        foreach (var t in _tasks) t.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(_tasks);
    }

    private void OnTaskCompleted(Task completedTask)
    {
        TaskCompleted?.Invoke(this, completedTask);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
        var taskRunner = new TaskBatchRunner(tasks.ToArray());
        taskRunner.TaskCompleted += MyTaskCompleted;
        taskRunner.Run();
        ...

    private void MyTaskCompleted(object sender, Task e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"task {e.Id} completed!");
    }
```